# Does the square root of a sum of squares grow more slowly than the sum of terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose I have a non-negative sequence $a_n \geq 0$ satisfying $\sum a_n = \infty$. I’m trying to show that

$\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum a_n}{\sqrt{\displaystyle \sum a_n^2}}=\infty$

Is this always true? It seems to be true for $a_n = 1/n$ and $a_n = n$.

Comment: You mean the limit of that quotient as $n\to\infty$, right?

Comment: The fact that the numerator is larger than the denominator is due to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is false for divergent geometric series (other than $a_n=1^n$)—for example, $a_n=2^n$. A heuristic that leads to this type of example is that the sum of a finite geometric series is basically the same size as the largest term.

Comment: +1: but II think you need to exclude the case of a geometric series with ratio $1$.

Answer (score -4):

An easier way is to take $a_n = 1$ for all $n$. Then $\displaystyle \sum a_n = \sum 1 = \infty$ while $\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum a_n}{\sqrt{\displaystyle \sum a_n^2}}= 1\neq \infty$ .

Comment: $\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum a_n}{\sqrt{\displaystyle \sum a_n^2}}= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}=\infty.$

Comment: This is incorrect - your example gives $\sqrt{n}$ which diverges.